# Getter-Setter method and Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, get, set

I have a class NewClass2 and a class with main method. Basically what I want to to is I wanna save a book title, release date, number of pages and the isbn number in an ArrayList and then print the Info.

```
public class NewClass2 {
    int pages;
    String released;
    String title;
    int isbn;



    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public String getReleased() {
        return released;
    }

    public void setReleased(String released) {
        this.released = released;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public NewClass2(int pages, String released, String title, int isbn) {
        this.pages = pages;
        this.released = released;
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public NewClass2() {
    }

    public void printInfo(){
        System.out.println("The book has "+pages+" pages and was released on "+released+" and is called "+title);
    }

}
```

And the main class:

```
    public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<NewClass2> listTest = new ArrayList<>( );
        listTest.add(new NewClass2( 200,"Book 1", "8.9.14",2222) );
        listTest.add(new NewClass2( 200,"Book 2", "1.2.04",5555) );
        listTest.add(new NewClass2( 200,"Book 3", "5.4.06",6666) );
        listTest.add(new NewClass2( 200,"Book 4", "7.4.13",7777) );
        listTest.add(new NewClass2( 200,"Book 5", "2.2.03",8888) );

        NewClass2 book = new NewClass2(listTest);

        book.printInfo();

    }
}
```

The IDE tells me that

```
NewClass2 book = new NewClass2(listTest);
```

is wrong but why? and how to i fix it??

Comment: Look at your declared class constructor -- then look at your the way you're calling constructor  -- they don't match.

Comment: There are two NewClass2 constructors. One takes no parameters and the other takes an int, String, String, and int: `public NewClass2(int pages, String released, String title, int isbn)`. You're calling a non-existing constructor and are passing in only one String. That's not going to work. You either have to call the default constructor without parameter or pass in an int, String, String, and int.

Comment: Note this all should be well explained in the constructor section of your java textbook or tutorial.

Comment: But aren't I passing a int, String, String, int in my ArrayList?

Comment: How is it ***wrong***?Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the following:

In "NewClass2" you have

1. a constructor for int pages, String released, String title and int
   isbn
2. a constructor for () {nothing}

To get every book of your ArrayList you could replace the following line

```
NewClass2 book = new NewClass2(listTest);
book.printInfo();
```

to

```
for (NewClass2 book : listTest){
    book.printInfo();
}
```

This would print the info of every book inside the ArrayList.

I hope that I could help you.